# Find sum and percentage of column in python (Pandas) from a pdf

Tags: python, json, pandas, parsing

I want to parse data from a PDF and then find sum and percentage of data:
My code looks like this:

```
import camelot 
import re
import pandas as pd
tables = camelot.read_pdf('result.pdf', pages="17")
marks = tables[0].df.iloc[[3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30],3:12]
print(marks)
marks.to_csv('sample.csv')
```

And I want to remove repeated content in btw ( ) so that only numbers remain:

```
3       4       5       6       7       8       9      10      11
3    52(B)  78(A+)  76(A+)  56(B+)   73(A)   74(A)  83(A+)  78(A+)   90(O)
6   40(P)*  58(B+)   52(B)   45(C)  57(B+)  55(B+)  83(A+)  82(A+)   90(O)
9   59(B+)  40(P)*  63(B+)  59(B+)  64(B+)   65(A)   91(O)  82(A+)  85(A+)
12  64(B+)   54(B)  78(A+)   42(P)   72(A)   73(A)  83(A+)  85(A+)  75(A+)
15   67(A)   44(P)       A   53(B)   65(A)  64(B+)  83(A+)  84(A+)  75(A+)
18  61(B+)   53(B)  64(B+)   42(P)   65(A)   49(C)  81(A+)  82(A+)   90(O)
21   44(P)   46(C)   68(A)  40(P)*   49(C)   51(B)  83(A+)  82(A+)  75(A+)
24   69(A)  77(A+)  76(A+)  62(B+)   71(A)  64(B+)  85(A+)  84(A+)  100(O)
27  78(A+)  78(A+)  83(A+)  76(A+)  79(A+)   69(A)  85(A+)  82(A+)   90(O)
30  87(A+)  84(A+)   90(O)   71(A)  82(A+)  81(A+)  87(A+)  84(A+)   95(O)
```

Then what should I do next to sum and hence find percentage?

Comment: Can you be more specific about percentages? In another words, what is expected output, e.g. first 2, 3 values?

Comment: All values, without ( ) and inside contents. And percentage will be sum of column divided by total number of rows

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) per each column by [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df = df.replace('\D+', '', regex=True).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
print (df)
     3   4     5   6   7   8   9  10   11
3   52  78  76.0  56  73  74  83  78   90
6   40  58  52.0  45  57  55  83  82   90
9   59  40  63.0  59  64  65  91  82   85
12  64  54  78.0  42  72  73  83  85   75
15  67  44   NaN  53  65  64  83  84   75
18  61  53  64.0  42  65  49  81  82   90
21  44  46  68.0  40  49  51  83  82   75
24  69  77  76.0  62  71  64  85  84  100
27  78  78  83.0  76  79  69  85  82   90
30  87  84  90.0  71  82  81  87  84   95
```

If remove only content of `()`:

```
df = df.replace('(\(.*\))', '', regex=True)
print (df)
      3    4   5    6   7   8   9  10   11
3    52   78  76   56  73  74  83  78   90
6   40*   58  52   45  57  55  83  82   90
9    59  40*  63   59  64  65  91  82   85
12   64   54  78   42  72  73  83  85   75
15   67   44   A   53  65  64  83  84   75
18   61   53  64   42  65  49  81  82   90
21   44   46  68  40*  49  51  83  82   75
24   69   77  76   62  71  64  85  84  100
27   78   78  83   76  79  69  85  82   90
30   87   84  90   71  82  81  87  84   95
```